# How do I take the information from 1 spreadsheet and count it on another spreadsheet based on a set range of values?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have 2 spreadsheets in the same work book. On the first, I have dates names and others values (y/n, amounts). I need to be able to put in a date range on the second spreadsheet and have it take data from the first sheet and give me totals.   I know how to write some basic formulas (`=sum(a2:a54)`, `=countif(b12:b34,5)`) but I don't know how to get it to grab a count from the first based on a date range I put in. I want to be able to put in one date in 1 cell (B3) and a later date in another cell (D3) and have it tell me how many times numbers or letters appear in a specified column on the first spreadsheet.

Comment: To simply get data from another sheet `='Sheet 1'!A1/(1024^2)`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a range in a third column based on start and end dates, then count the number of occurrences of the Search value with COUNTIF.

[image]